# Visual Studio 2013 - git checkout

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013

I would like some help with git functionality within VS 2013. From what I have understood there is no checkout command. Instead there is a “revert” option.
However, when I hit revert, VS asks me to resolve conflicts which doesn’t make sense (since I am only checking out, not merging).

Besides this, once I have reverted to an older commit I have only two options: **commit revert** or **undo revert**. If I choose **undo revert** I can no longer revert to any other commit (revert is greyed out). 
This is a problem in the following case: I am looking for the commit that introduced a certain bug. I revert to “5d” but this is also buggy. I want to revert to the even older “3a” so I hit undo revert. But now I can no longer revert again (greyed out).

What am I doing wrong? Is there another way to check out?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I suggest just using Git Extensions or something similar. VS 2013 Git support is fairly weird but the repositories  are compatible with more normal Git tools.